# Xcode 6 moving views instead of rotating in Debug View Hierarchy

Tags: xcode, uiview-hierarchy

Is there possible to move the views instead of rotating them when dragging around in the `Debug View Hierarchy` pane? It zooms in the center by default but I want to see some details of a view in the bottom part of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how could I not figured this out sooner. Using a Magic Mouse, simply swipe on it (scroll) horizontally or vertically to move the entire View Hierarchy.